# Can a service use Windows Raw Input API?

Tags: winapi, service, windows-services

Windows Raw Input API requires a window to listen WM_INPUT messages. But, service has no window handle like a console application.
How can we use Windows Raw Input API on a service? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

A service can create an HWND, but it will not be running in an interactive workstation, and window messages cannot pass across workstation boundaries.  So I do not think it is possible to use Raw Input in a service.